# Can't install MVC 6 beta 6 in an MVC app using .NET 4.6 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 app which targeted .NET 4.5.2. In Visual Studio 2015 Pro I uninstalled MVC 5.2.3 through the Package manager Console and it was successful. I changed the target .NET framework to 4.6. When I tried to install MVC 5 beta 6, I get the error below. Why? I thought any pre .NET 4.6 assembly can be used in .NET 4.6.

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta6'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Comment: I don't think the error message is saying that you can't use .Net Framework 4.6, I think it means you need DNX 4.5.1 or above.

Comment: I don't know what you're saying. A nuget package installer should be downloading and installing all dependencies. Is there something I need to install manually?